# Duplicate insert into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Im using the following code and testing it using `WAMP` on my localhost.

It works fine and inserts the data however for some reason it creates duplicate row.

Is there are reason why it makes it appear twice?

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$name =$_POST["name"];
$surname = $_POST["surname"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$userpass = $_POST["password"];

$mysql_qry = "insert into employee_data(name, surname, age, username, password) values ('$name', '$surname', '$age', '$username', '$userpass')";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);

if ($conn->query($mysql_qry) === TRUE){
    echo "insert success";
}
else{
    echo "Error:" .$mysql_qry . "<br> " . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: Please read about **[SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**. Instead of building queries with string concatenation, use **[prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)** with **[bound parameters](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)**. See **[this page](https://phptherightway.com/#databases)** and **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)** for some good examples.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use **[PHP's built-in functions](//php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the password_hash() **[compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)** (and you should consider upgrading to a supported version of PHP). Make sure you **[don't escape passwords](//stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so changes the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES, you run the query TWICE, see comments in the code

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$name =$_POST["name"];
$surname = $_POST["surname"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$userpass = $_POST["password"];

$mysql_qry = "insert into employee_data
                        (name, surname, age, username, password) 
                values ('$name', '$surname', '$age', '$username', '$userpass')";

//ONCE HERE
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);

//AND AGAIN HERE
if ($conn->query($mysql_qry) === TRUE){
    echo "insert success";
}
else{
    echo "Error:" .$mysql_qry . "<br> " . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

> ALSO Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
>   Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Coded using prepared and bound queries

```
<?php
require "conn.php";

$sql = "insert into employee_data
                        (name, surname, age, username, password) 
                values (?,?,?,?,?)";

$stmt = $conn-prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('sssss', $_POST["name"],
                            $_POST["surname"];
                            $_POST["username"];
                            $_POST["password"];

if ( $stmt->execute() ){
    echo "insert success";
}else{
    echo "Error:" .$mysql_qry . "<br> " . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

> Now I have to mention how bad it is to use Plain Text Password.
>
> PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
>   and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
>   And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: WIll do sir, Thank you for your tips.

Comment: @BBen also make sure that when you use password_hash() / password_verify()   you write the query as `SELECT password FROM user WHERE username  = :username`  **do not include password column in the where** as `SELECT password FROM user WHERE username  = :username AND password = :password` As RDMS are designed to return a result as quickly as possible in most cases in constant stabile time when indexes/buffer pools are involved a [Timing attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack) in the SQL engine can be possible

Comment: Do I also need to use prepared parameters for when I use mysqli_connect? Or sql injection cannot happen before I even connect to the data base? For example: $conn = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $db_name);